# baby crying at the time of mila is an עת רצון

Tags: sources-mekorot, brit-milah, baby-infant

Someone once told me that when the baby cries at the time of mila it's an עת רצון, a time of will.
Does anyone know the source for this?

Comment: Please [edit] in as much information as you can about where you've heard of this concept.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1229/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rav Shlomo Ephraim (author of the Kli Yakor on the Torah) writes in [עוללות אפרים siman 415](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38157&st=&pgnum=176)  this idea, with regards to the baby crying specifically being an eis ratzon see here in [Siman 470](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38157&st=&pgnum=195)

Comment: What exactly are you referring to inn the Ollelos Ephraim?

Comment: It's in middle of piece

Comment: I read again just to be sure, but I really don't see what you are referring to. If you can quote the actual sentence it might help clear things up.

Comment: It's in middle sdarshu Razal...חנני ה' כי אמלל אני ...

Comment: That's not what he's saying. Mosheh Rabebeinu is praying and mentioning mila as a protection against those angels of destruction. He doesn't say that any time a child is crying from a mila than anyone can daven.

Comment: Rav Gutmacher uses that as the idea

Comment: The idea goes on that passuk of Tehillim mentioned in that piece refering to the pain of milah

Comment: I'm not saying its not a good source to base a drasha off of, I'm just saying that's not what he's saying.

Comment: So your question is on Rav Guttmacher

Comment: Well i haven't seen his words so no.

Comment: @user6591 see my edit

Answer (score 7):

A source that the time the child cries at a Bris is an עת רצון is the notes of Rabbi Eliyahu Guttmacher Zatzal on Mesechtas Shabbos 130a. This is mentioned in the [Sefer Aderes Eliyahu](http://books.google.com/books/about/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95.html?id=-OuaSwAACAAJ). He writes שבזמן שהתינוק בוכה מצער המילה, עת רצון היא.

Comment: Thanks! Can you send me the link to this?

Comment: why is it an עת רצון when the child cries at them Milah?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge not online. If I can take a picture of the page somewhere, I will put the picture up.

Comment: +1 But I've heard too many chassidish and Yeshivish people say this for this to be the only source:)

Comment: @user6591: I wrote "A source"

Comment: @GershonGold: Can you atleast send me link to Shabbos 130a?

Comment: You can get it yourself very easily

Comment: @GershonGold: I looked in Shabbos 130a and nowhere did the Gemara say mention anything about עת רצון.

Comment: I did not say it is in Shabbos 130a. I said it is in the notes of Rabbi Eliyahu Guttmacher Zatzal on Mesechtas Shabbos 130a